# Attaching a usage plan to a public Api Gateway Endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, api-key

For learning purposes, I have developed a front-end application in Angular with AWS as back-end.

As this is a didactic project, I must prevent any possible costs explosion. Overall, for what concerns API Gateway calls.

At the moment, I have a single public GET endpoint for providing the information to the public homepage in the front-end.

I need to attach a usage plan to this endpoint for limiting the maximum number of calls to this endpoint. For example, max 10000 calls/week.

I already tried with an **API-KEY**:

- Created the Usage Plan with "Quota: 10,000 requests per week"
- Created the API KEY connected to the Usage Plan
- Connected the API KEY to the authentication method of the endpoint

It works, but in this way I need to hard code the API KEY on the front-end.

I know that hard coding sensitive information on the front-end is a bad practice, but I thought that in this case the API KEY is needed only for connecting a Usage Plan, not for securing private information or operations. So I'm not sure if in this case it should be acceptable or not.

Is this solution safe, or could the same API KEY be used for other malicious purposes?

Are there any other solutions?

Answer (score 2):

To add to the other answer, API Keys are not Authorization Tokens.

API Keys associated with Usage Plans are sent to the gateway on the `x-api-key` header (by default).

Tokens used by authorizers live on the standard `Authorization` header.

Use API Keys to set custom throttling and quotas for a particular caller, but you still need an Authorizer on any secure endpoints.

You can optionally set an API Key to be returned from the Authorizer when using a custom authorizer to be applied to the Usage Plan, which prevents you from having to distribute keys to clients in addition to their secrets.

[APIG Key Source Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-api-key-source.html)

Answer (score 0):

As [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-api-usage-plans.html#apigateway-usage-plans-best-practices) says, generally you wouldn't want to rely on a hardcoded API key for authentication.

In addition, based on the information you provided, the usage plan limits are tied to the use by the user of the API key. So you could also set up [throttling on the account or stage itself](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-throttling.html).

Finally, if it's possible, you could set up security group rules on your server or access control lists on your vpc that is serving your front end so that not everyone can access it.

Other ideas are to shut down the API gateway when you aren't using it and also rotate the API key frequently.

Obviously none of these are going to be enough if this were hosting sensitive information or doing anything remotely important. But as long as the only information in the client side is that API Key to access the API Gateway and that API Gateway itself doesn't interact with anything sensitive that's probably enough for a learning project.

But you should do all of this at your own risk as for all you know I'm the person who's going to try to hack you ;)

Comment: Yes i set the Throttle for my method, but i'm not sure it's enough. I set a max of 2 calls/second. In a month i could reach 6M calls!

Do you know if i can set a global limit of 100000 calls/month?